# Editable popup textarea for table td

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a textarea in the td cell of each row in column 3, to hold description specific to each row.
When the user clicks on the td, the current description in the textarea inside the td should be copied over to the textarea inside #div_toggle

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

The user would make changes to the description in #div_toggle, and when done, will click 'X' to close the div. This should cause the contents to be transferred from the textarea in #div_toggle to the td cell textarea.

Would you be able to help me achieve this goal? Or am I complicating this? Is there a better approach?
Below is the code I have thus far, but it does not work as desired or described above. Please help.
Best regards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        th,
        td {
            border: solid 1px lightgrey;
        }

        #div_toggle {
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #div_toggle textarea {
            width: 200px;
            height: 150px;
            border: 3px solid #cccccc;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        #close_text {
            position: absolute;
            right: 27px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #cfd0d1;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //Show textarea
            $('.cell_id').click(function() {
                $('#div_toggle').slideToggle('slow');
            });

            //Close textarea
            $('#close_text').click(function() {
                var tbl = $('#itemtable');
                var rows = $('tr', tbl);
                //get toggle div text area contents into td cell textarea
                rows.eq(clickedrowindex).find('td:nth-child(3)').text() = $('#div_toggle textarea#notescopy').val();                
                $('#div_toggle').slideToggle('slow');
            });

            var clickedrowindex;
            $('#itemtable').find('tr').click( function(){
                clickedrowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
                //get td cell textarea contents into the toggle div text area
                var notestext = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
                $('#div_toggle textarea#notescopy').val(notestext);
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="left" style="margin-top:5px; border: solid #666 1px;">
            <table id="itemtable" class="" style="width: 300px; margin: 10px;">
                <thead style="color:black;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> 2013</td>
                    <td> Toyota</td>
                    <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>   
                    <td> 2001</td>
                    <td> Honda</td>
                    <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'></textarea></td>                
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    
            <div id="div_toggle"><textarea id='notescopy'></textarea>
                <span id="close_text" title="Click to close">X</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify what problem you're having with your code.  You've described what you want it to do... at what part is it not behaving as you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need that much of `code` and its can simplified to just `two` functions to achieve your desired results.

Firstly, we just need to make sure that we save the our current `target` (td > textarea) in `variable` and use that `variable` to assign `val` to the `textarea` accordingly.

Also, we need to use a `class` `.div_toggle` selector not an id `#div_toggle` - Since id will only pick the element which is found firstly but in our case we need to change value dynamically on each `slideDown` and `SlideUp` event.

Lastly, for this you need to use `slideDown` and `slideUp` on `X` button click. Its work the same way as `slideToggle`. Using `slideToggle` will create a **weird** behaviour.

When you click the `X` the content you typed in the toggle div textarea will be transfered to the `td` you `clicked` on as your `target`

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let currentTar; //save current target
  let divToggle = $('.div_toggle') //get element

  //Show textarea
  $('.cell_id').click(function(event) {
    currentTar = event.currentTarget
    divToggle.slideDown('slow');
    let getText = $(this).find('textarea').val()
    divToggle.find('textarea').val(getText)

  });

  //Close textarea
  $('#close_text').click(function() {
    divToggle.slideUp('slow');
    let assignVal = divToggle.find('textarea').val();
    $(currentTar).find('textarea').val(assignVal)
  });
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
}

.div_toggle {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.div_toggle textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#close_text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #cfd0d1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="left" style="margin-top:5px; border: solid #666 1px;">
    <table id="itemtable" class="" style="width: 300px; margin: 10px;">
      <thead style="color:black;">
        <tr>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> 2013</td>
          <td> Toyota</td>
          <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'>Test</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 2001</td>
          <td> Honda</td>
          <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'>Foo</textarea></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> 2040</td>
      <td> Elon Musk</td>
      <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'>Tesla</textarea> 
 </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="div_toggle"><textarea id='notescopy'></textarea>
      <span id="close_text" title="Click to close">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you again.... your solution worked like a charm!, I want to accept your answer now, but not sure if stackoverflow would allow me to add a long comment like this one, once I accept your answer.  One last thing left, that is, I want to position the toggle div along the top right corner or the left edge of the description table cell being clicked on. I tried to add position:absolute, left, and right properties to the toggle div, and gave it a z-index of 20. The table would grow in size, and doing it this way will not attach it to the table cell being clicked.Any ideas?ThankU

Comment: @user765081 Comments can be added anytime on an answer regardless of answer accepted after or before and i will be happy to help where i can. You want to position it next to `td` is that what you are saying ? This seems to total CSS job to be honest. Ideally according to stackoverlfow we need to open a new thread for something which is different then the original question this way this question and answer will help user looking specifically for this solution. i hope you understand :)

Comment: Okay, thank you, I got it. I will do some more research myself before I post a new question. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @user765081 No worries. Thanks heaps - happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

A few minor changes. Utilize `$(this).val()` instead of doing a `find` for the `closest` :)

You'll notice the code is much cleaner as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("textarea").click(function(){
    var contents = $(this).val();
    $('#notescopy').val(contents);
  });

  //Show textarea
  $('.cell_id').click(function() {
    $('#div_toggle').slideToggle('slow');
  });

  //Close textarea
  $('#close_text').click(function() {
    $('#div_toggle').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
}

#div_toggle {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

#div_toggle textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#close_text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #cfd0d1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="left" style="margin-top:5px; border: solid #666 1px;">
    <table id="itemtable" class="" style="width: 300px; margin: 10px;">
      <thead style="color:black;">
        <tr>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> 2013</td>
          <td> Toyota</td>
          <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 2001</td>
          <td> Honda</td>
          <td class='cell_id'><textarea name='reqnotes'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="div_toggle"><textarea id='notescopy'></textarea>
      <span id="close_text" title="Click to close">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```